# Adding certain amount of time to any date structure in C++

Tags: c++, date, time, addition

With given date (most likely in format YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS)
I want to add or substract another structure like (YYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS), and I am looking to do it most standard way (not implementing everything myself), so are there any POSIX like tools or perhaps boost component with give funcionallity ?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: You realize that what you want isn't always possible, right? What should the result be when you add 1 month plus 1 day to Jan 30?

Comment: I'd like to suggest parsing the formatted string to a localtime (struct tm) and then use 'mktime' to make it into a Unixtimestamp. (Plain Integer) or simply operating from the tm.

Comment: You should consider to distinguish the string representation and internal date/time data representation.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html

Answer (score 1):

As Dan O already said, Boost Date Time [parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_objects) + [calculations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#date_time.calculations)